# meaning of this Gnome terminal script

Tags: gnome-terminal

What is the meaning of this code: `gnome-terminal --tab -e "sh -c 'ch/home/Desktop'"\`

could you tell me the meaning of each part of this code, one by one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that code doesn't mean much, most likely. The breakdown is:

- `gnome-terminal`: this is the default terminal emulator of the Gnome desktop environment. This command will open a terminal, everything that comes after it is options and arguments that modify what `gnome-terminal` will do. These are:
- `--tab` : this will open a new tab in your currently open terminal.
- `-e`: this tells `gnome-terminal` to run a command when it launches.

In your case, the command is `sh -c 'ch/home/Desktop'` which means "use the shell `sh` to run the shell script found at `ch/home/Desktop`.

Now, that path is almost certainly wrong, since it expects to find a local directory named `ch` which has a subdirectory named `home` which in turn contains a subdirectory named `Desktop`. While it is possible that you have these directories on your system, it seems unlikely and you probably want `/home/<YOUR USERNAME>/Desktop`.

Next, this is almost certainly a directory and not a shell script (which is a file). So you can't actually run it with `sh`. I am guessing you wanted to do something very different, perhaps pass the path to a script you have saved on your desktiop. If so, assuming your user name is `skinner` and the script is at `/home/skinner/Desktop/my_script.sh`, you would do:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -e "sh -c '/home/skinner/Desktop/my_script.sh'"
```

Finally, the trailing `\` at the end is most likely a typo, but it will block execution if you include it since having `\` at the end of the line "escapes" the end of the line character (newline, `\n`) which tells the system the command continues on the next line, so it will only be executed after you hit enter again.

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what i need. Much appreciation brother.